# Control Dock.Top order without InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, winforms

We are not supposed to modify the contents of `InitializeComponent()`.  Yet, the order that the designer adds our controls determines the stack order of Docking.  For example, the designer might generate:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
            //...
            this.Controls.Add(this.dockTop); 
            this.Controls.Add(this.dockTop2);
```

Where dockTop and dockTop2 are of type `Panel` with `Dock = DockStyle.Top`.  This results in dockTop2 at the top of the `Form`.  If I want `dockTop2` at the top of the form, then I have to modify the designer file (which we are not supposed to do as the changes can be over-written).

So, how can I set the order of my docking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order isn't set by the designer, it is set by you.  Initially by the order in which you add controls.  You can alter the order by right-clicking a control and choosing Bring to Front or Send to Back.  Get fine-grained control over the order with View + Other Windows + Document Outline.  You can drag+drop a control in the list to move it.

Comment: Wow, great info.  I find it a bit strange that the order displayed in DocumentOutline is in reverse of what you get with `Dock.Top`.

Comment: You can also do it yourself from code. 
There is Control.BringToFront() and Control.SendToBack().

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to manipulate a form containing several docked controls, as I understand it, is to **Cut** the panels, groupboxes, whatever and **Paste** them back in in order of precedence.